# How can i remove these weird artifacts in VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCODE for web development with flask. I'm getting these weird white artifacts while coding.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its caused by having nvidia image sharpening turned on globally in the Nvidia Control panel. Disable it, and enable it on a per app/game basis.

Answer (score 1):

[Sean's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14146846/sean) answer didn't work for me but guided me to another solution. By uninstalling everything related to Nvidia drivers and reinstalling them the artifacts stopped showing up for me on VS Code.